# How do you change the sprite position in a animation? KineticJs

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I the speech bubbles to be next to the person who says them but how do I change the position? I don't want to have any more animations for that, is it possible?
link: http://www.tlu.ee/~kristo93/Eritamine%20-%20puhas/p6hi.html
for example the next tere would be positioned next to the students.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always an X-Y co-ordinate of any group or element you create using the kinetic.js
You just need to manipulate X-Y property of the group containing your speech cloud.
suppose your reference to that cloud group is called cloudGroup then set the X and Y property using the method as follows:

`cloudGroup.setX(100);`

`cloudGroup.setY(100);`

So just insert anything instead of 100, which suits the position you desire.